# I'm unable to store data in AsyncStorage. It just shows as [object Object]

Tags: react-native

OK, so I've got some data/strings stored in a component's state. But when I try to store that data to AsyncStorage, I'm unable to store it and retrieve it across another screen. I tried to display the data in alert but the laert box displayed the message:
Registered user details: [object Object]

I've confirmed that the state object contains the correct data i.e. fullname, username and password are all strings. Could you please help or tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
registerUser(){
    AsyncStorage.setItem('fullname', this.state.fullname);
    AsyncStorage.setItem('username', this.state.username);
    AsyncStorage.setItem('password', this.state.password);
   // alert("Full name: " + this.state.fullname);
   alert("Registered user details: " + AsyncStorage.getItem('fullname'));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**AsyncStorage** is an asynchronous repository. Switch function to asynchronous.

```js
async registerUser(){
  await  AsyncStorage.setItem('fullname', this.state.fullname);
  await  AsyncStorage.setItem('username', this.state.username);
  await  AsyncStorage.setItem('password', this.state.password);
  let getdata = await AsyncStorage.getItem('fullname');
   alert("Registered user details: " + getdata);
```

Comment: Thanks, I upvoted your answer but StackOverflow says "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."

Comment: I did. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @user11954202 I hope you will experience a lot of things with React-Native in the future.

Answer (score 0):

change the function to asynchronous

```
    registerUser = async () => {
      try {
        await  AsyncStorage.setItem('fullname', this.state.fullname);
        await  AsyncStorage.setItem('username', this.state.username);
        await  AsyncStorage.setItem('password', this.state.password);
        let getdata = await AsyncStorage.getItem('fullname');
        alert("Registered user details: " + getdata);
      } catch (e) {
        // saving error
      }
    }
```